# WAMP server not accessible from a different computer on the same network

Tags: apache, wamp

I have on my laptop a WAMP server as my local server. On this server i am hosting a webpage just for local use.

I also have registered a free domain name for my server from dyndns.org. I'm using dynamic DNS by running a software from dyndns.org.

When i try to access my server and view the website which i am hosting on it using my browser, by typing localhost or my free domain name, it works just fine.

But the problem is that when a friend of mine sitting right next to me(on the same local network) tries to visit my webpage from his laptop, he gets an error message saying: 
**"You don't have permissions to access this server"** .

I configure the httpd.conf file after i installed the WAMP server and changed only the DocumentRoot and the Directory to a folder of my choice inside the www folder.
Also i changed the ServerName to be my free domain name.

I don't think that the above are the problem.  So , anyone has a clue of what might be wrong here ?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try writing this:

```
<Directory yourdir>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. Will try as soon as i get home and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

Nope neither that worked. But after messing around with the httpd.conf file i found the solution. In the

```
< Directory yourdir >
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all

# I had to put this line also
Require all granted

< /Directory>
```